# How to map only selected fields using mapstruct

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

How do I map only selected fields with mapStructand return thenm as response.

Ex:

```
class Location {
         
   String street;
          
   String unit;
    
   int postCode;
 
 }

public class Car {
 
    private Location location;.
}

public class CarDto {

  private Location location;

}
```

Now I can map them using :

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {
 
    CarMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CarMapper.class ); 
 
   CarDto returnObject =  CarDto carToCarDto(Car car); 
}
```

Now, `returnObject`  will contain location which will have `street, unit and postCode`.

But , I want to expose just the `street and postCode` with returnObject.location.

How can I expose only those selected fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to only map certain fields and ignore everything else you can use `BeanMapping#ignoreByDefault`.

e.g.

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

    CarMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CarMapper.class ); 
 
    @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    @Mapping(target = "street", source = "location.street")
    @Mapping(target = "postCode", source = "location.postCode")
    CarDto carToCarDto(Car car); 

}
```

By using `@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)` you are ignoring all properties. And by using the `@Mapping` you are defining which properties you want to map.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how could this possibly work, considering that the target `CarDto` doesn't have `street` or `postCode` properties? I would expect this to fail compile with `Unknown property "street" in result type CarDto.CarDtoBuilder` or something like that.

Comment: The target need to have `location` into them. However, the main point of the a answer is the `BeanMapping#ignoreByDefault`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore some field in target object, just simple indicate it in MapStruct `@Mapping` annotation, like below:

```
@Mapping(target = "location.postCode", ignore = true)
CarDto carToCarDto(Car car);
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your CarDto like this :

```
public class CarDto {

   String street;
   int postCode;

}
```

And in your mapper :

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {
 
   CarMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CarMapper.class ); 
 
   @Mapping(source = "location.street", target = "street")
   @Mapping(source = "location.postCode", target = "postCode")
   CarDto returnObject =  CarDto carToCarDto(Car car); 
}
```

Comment: The aim of the mapper will be map any fields anc containing fields. Its impractical to unpack all composition proporties in the CarDTO class.